# How do I keep Apple Mail from resizing images in my HTML signature?

Tags: html, osx, e-mail

I created an HTML email signature for my company, and have everything working. It contains both text and an image containing HTML links to our website, and all looks well until I add it in the signature section of Apple's Mail. The text part stays as it should, but no matter what size I set the image to, Mail resizes it to be gigantic.

How do I change the size of the image to what I want without losing the link to our website?

Comment: Did you write inline css width and height for the image?

Comment: You could also have asked this at http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Fiksdal It is also on-topic here, though :)

Comment: @Vincent Sure, didn't mean to imply otherwise :)

Comment: @Fiksdal No harm done. We do have a bit of a streak of people voting good content as off-topic, so I'm a bit jealous of good questions that are also fitting for other stacks.

Answer (score 2):

HTML signatures in Apple Mail are a nightmare, Mail adds all sorts of strange markup to your HTML and its not easy to get at the actual HTML it outputs.

You can find more info on editing the HTML for you signature directly in this article:

- [How to Make an HTML Signature in Apple Mail](http://matt.coneybeare.me/how-to-make-an-html-signature-in-apple-mail-for-el-capitan-os-x-10-dot-11/)

As a rule with HTML emails you should code like it's 1999. Use tables for your layout and only use inline styles. It's horrible, and nigh on blasphemous in regular web development but email clients are decades behind modern browsers.

In short: Use tables for your layout and use a single table cell for your image (with the width set on the table and/or cell itself).

Answer (score 0):

you can use Signature Manager app (http://signaturemanager.eu/) to take care of that - it helps with creating a proper HTML code that Mail.app doesn't change on it's whim

Comment: Hi Alex, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!